# Python: Add pdb in middle of if statement

Tags: python

Is there a way to add a debugger right before an `else` statement in python? For example, I'm trying to do:

```
a = 5
if a > 3:
    print("yes")
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
else:
    print("no")
```

Having the `pdb.set_trace()` right before the `else` statement causes a SyntaxError. Is there a way around this?

EDIT: This example is a simplification of a much larger case. I would like to use it where I have many `elif` statements, so putting it inside each `if`, `elif`, and `else` is not desirable. Here's another example:

```
if not root:
    root = node
pdb.set_trace()
elif node.val < root.val:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

I want to start the debugger before I evaluate `node.val` because I could have an AttributeError if `val` is missing.

Comment: Indent it to the if block or else block!

Comment: @Nishant But then I miss it if the `if` block is not entered.

Comment: @jss367 best way to import it would be before if  statement

Comment: When should it be called? Only if the true `if` block is executed (at the end), only if `else` block is executed (at the beginning), or both?

Comment: I want it called only if the first `if` statement isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can cover both branches like this:

```
a = 5
if a > 3:
    print("yes")
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
else:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    print("no")
```

or just put it before and *step* through it.

```
a = 5
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if a > 3:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code actually looks like this:

```
a = 5
if a > 3:
    print("yes")
elif a > 2:
    print("maybe")
elif a > 1:
    print("not really")
else:
    print("no")
```

An option can be to add an additional `if` level which needs only a minor rewrite and indentation adjustment

```
a = 5
if a > 3:
    print("yes")
else:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    if a > 2:
        print("maybe")
    elif a > 1:
        print("not really")
    else:
        print("no")
```